# Scoring sentences in a text file using word repitition

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am making a Java program which scores sentences and display sentences with higher scores. What I am trying to do is read the text file, split information in the text file into separate sentences, calculate the number of words repeated inside the text file, give a score to the sentences that consist of repeated words, then finally display the sentences with scores more than 1.

So far I have managed to split each sentence and now I am trying to give a score to each repeated word. Following code shows my progress.

However, the for loop in the above code doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: amongst possibly other things, `j<=uniqueKeyIndex` is wrong. should be `<`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map for your problem actualy, mapping the words to count as this
Then for your scoring function

```
private static void score(String sentence){
 Map<String,Integer> score = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
 for(String key : sentence.split(" ")){
    if(score.get(key) == null) score.put(key,0);
    score.put(key,score.get(key)+1);
 }
 //Printing scores for your keys, you can add the case where your key is= to 'a , the ,and ...'
 for (String key : score .keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + key+" Score : "+score.get(key));
 }
}
```

Inside your for loop you can do :

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentenceList.size(); i++) {
   score(sentenceList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: inside your for loop, when getting the sentence from your sentence list,  you can call the function score( sentenceList.get(i));

Comment: it prints it out now. however, it doesn't identify whether the word is being repeated. if the word is being repeated, it gives  score of 1 to the particular word in 2 different occasions. However, I want it to show score 2 if the word is repeated twice

Comment: I have edited my for loop in the above code. Please check what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Also it seems to go on forever. When it finishes reading it, it loops back to the top and does it again.